# Pass values from Apex Script to LWC JS

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript, toast

I have built an LWC Component to display a Toast message without clicking a button.  I plan to add this to our Portal so we can display custom messages.  I have created a Custom Object, PortalMessages__c, with fields to build/customize the Toast Message - title, message, mode, etc..  I would like to have the Toast Message output the values from the most recent active Portal Message record.
In LWC I can only get records by ID so I built the a simple Apex class to query the PortalMessage__c Object and output the records to a list - PortalToastMessage_Controller.
I am having issues referencing the first record in my list from my LWC - see the title field in my notification.

**LWC.js**

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import getPortalMessages from '@salesforce/apex/PortalToastMessage_Controller.getPortalMessages';

export default class portalToastMessage extends LightningElement {
    
    @wire(getPortalMessages) wiredPortalMessages;

    constructor(){
        super();
        for(let i=0; i<this.wiredPortalMessages.length; i++){
            console.log(this.wiredPortalMessages[0].Title__c);
        }
    }

    notification() {
        const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: this.wiredPortalMessages[0].Title__c,
            message: "We have made changes to our Customer Portal.  To learn more click {0}!",
            variant: "info",
            mode: "sticky",
            messageData: [
                {
                    url: 'https://www.google.com/',
                    label: 'here'
                },
            ]
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        this.notification();
    }
}
```

**Apex Class**

```
public with sharing class PortalToastMessage_Controller {

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<PortalMessage__c> getPortalMessages() {
        return [
            Select
                Id,
                IsActive__c,
                Message__c,
                Mode__c,
                Title__c,
                Url__c,
                UrlLabel__c,
                Variant__c 
            From PortalMessage__c
            Where 
                IsActive__c = true
                And ExpiryDate__c>today 
            Order by createddate desc    
        ];  
    }
}
```

Comment: The referenced question's answer points you to two important bits of documentation that will help you understand when the wire is called and how this will be later than you seem to think. Use of a constructor is rarely needed in LWC, and certainly too early.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Phil - that was helpful.  I updated the LWC accordingly

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import getPortalMessages from '@salesforce/apex/PortalToastMessage_Controller.getPortalMessages';

export default class portalToastMessage extends LightningElement {
    messages; 

    @wire(getPortalMessages) wiredMessages({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.messages = data;
            this.error = undefined;
            this.notification()
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.messages = undefined;
        }
    }

    notification() {
        const event = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: this.messages[0].Title__c,
            message: this.messages[0].Message__c,
            variant: this.messages[0].Variant__c,
            mode: this.messages[0].Mode__c,
            messageData: [
                {
                    url: this.messages[0].Url__c,
                    label: this.messages[0].UrlLabel__c
                },
            ]
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
}
```